# ID chunks of rows by start and end value

Tags: r, data.table

I need to ID chunks of rows in a data.table by a start-row and an end-row criteria. In the MWE below, the start-row is defined by colA=="d", and the group continues until colA=="a"

```
library(data.table)
in.data <- data.table(colA=c("b", "f", "b", "k", "d", "b", "a", "s", "a", "n", "d", "f", "d", "a", "t"))
in.data$wanted.column <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA)

in.data
#     colA wanted.column
#  1:    b            NA
#  2:    f            NA
#  3:    b            NA
#  4:    k            NA
#  5:    d             1
#  6:    b             1
#  7:    a             1
#  8:    s            NA
#  9:    a            NA
# 10:    n            NA
# 11:    d             2
# 12:    f             2
# 13:    d             2
# 14:    a             2
# 15:    t            NA
```

(It doesn't matter if out-of-group values are NA, zero or any other identifiable result)

Comment: wanted.column is the desired output. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: does colA always have at least one "d" followed by the same number of "a"s ?

Comment: Yes, after all "d" there is an "a", and the group goes from the "d" to the first "a" after it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't answer question properly. Yes, colA always has one or more "d", and there are same amount of "a" or more.

Comment: what behavior do you expect for 'd'...,'a'..,'a' ? do you want the first or the second 'a' ?

Comment: group ends with first "a"

Comment: I can tell you that, that's a tough one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE

The original version of the answer looked for the shortest sequences, which was not right because they can contain starting symbol in the middle, e.g. `c('d','f','d','a')`. The edited version of the answer fixes this problem

### UPDATE2

I was informed that when two sequences follow each other (e.g. `in.data <- data.table(colA=c("b", "f", "b", "k", "d", "b", "a", "d", "f", "d", "a", "t"))`), they are enumerated as one solution, which is wrong. Here, I fix this problem by keeping track of the occurences of `symbol.stop` symbols in `colA`.

**Setup**

```
library(data.table)
in.data <- data.table(colA=c("b", "f", "b", "k", "d", "b", "a", "s", "a", "n", "d", "f", "d", "a", "t"))
symbol.start='d'
symbol.stop='a'
```

**Actual code**

```
in.data[,y := rev(cumsum(rev(colA)==symbol.stop))][,out:=(!match(symbol.start,colA,nomatch=.N+1)>1:.N),by=y]

in.data$out[in.data$out] <- as.factor(max(in.data$y)-in.data$y[in.data$out])
```

Here, `[,y := rev(cumsum(rev(colA)==symbol.stop))]` creates a column `y` that can be used to group the data set by the occurrences of `symbol.stop` from the back side. The `[,out:=(!match(symbol.start,colA,nomatch=.N+1)>1:.N),by=y]` expression returns a boolean vector that tells whether a row belongs to the `start.symbol...end.symbol` sequence. The next line is needed to enumerate such sequences.

**Clean up and output**

```
in.data$y <- NULL   

in.data
#     colA out
#  1:    b   0
#  2:    f   0
#  3:    b   0
#  4:    k   0
#  5:    d   1
#  6:    b   1
#  7:    a   1
#  8:    s   0
#  9:    a   0
# 10:    n   0
# 11:    d   2
# 12:    f   2
# 13:    d   2
# 14:    a   2
# 15:    t   0
```

### UPDATE3

Just in case somebody needs it, the one-liner solution:

```
in.data[     , y := rev(cumsum(rev(colA)==symbol.stop))
      ][     , z:=(!match(symbol.start,colA,nomatch=.N+1)>1:.N), by=y
      ][ z==T, out:=as.numeric(factor(y,levels=unique(y)))
      ][     , c('z','y'):=list(NULL,NULL)]
```

Comment: It seems to work, and is very fast. @Khashaa, what did you see that is wrong?

Comment: @Khashaa seems to be right here. Check rows 11,12,13. They should be 2,2,2 not 0,0,2

Comment: Nice solution, Marat. I found some inconsistency when I run your code for `in.data <- data.table(colA=c("b", "f", "b", "k", "d", "b", "a", "d", "f", "d", "a", "t"))`. Perfect solution if you fix that.

Comment: On this example: `set.seed(45L); in.data = data.table(colA = sample(letters[1:20], 100, TRUE))`, the final one-liner doesn't return the correct result.. IIUC?

Comment: @Arun: you mean the group 3 that trails to the end of the data set? It's not a bug, because as OP says '..after all "d" there is an "a"...', so I'd rather say that the input set is incorrect

Comment: Oh I see. Dint notice that before, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure someone will come up with a nice `data.table` solution. While waiting, here's another `base` possibility:

```
in.df <- as.data.frame(in.data)

# index of "d", start index
start <- which(in.df$colA == "d")

# index of "a"
idx_a <- which(in.df$colA == "a")

# end index: for each start index, select the first index of "a" which is larger
end <- a[sapply(start, function(x) which.max(x < idx_a))]

# check if runs overlap and create groups of runs
lag_end <- c(0, head(end, -1))
run <- cumsum(start >= lag_end)

df <- data.frame(start, end, run)

# within each run, expand the sequence of idx, from min(start) to max(end)
df2 <- do.call(rbind,
        by(df, df$run, function(x){
          data.frame(run = x$run, idx = min(x$start):max(x$end))
        })
)

# add an empty 'run' variable to in.df
in.df$run <- NA

# assign df2$run at idx in in.data
in.df$run[df2$idx] <- df2$run

#    idx colA wanted.column run
# 1    1    b            NA  NA
# 2    2    f            NA  NA
# 3    3    b            NA  NA
# 4    4    k            NA  NA
# 5    5    d             1   1
# 6    6    b             1   1
# 7    7    a             1   1
# 8    8    s            NA  NA
# 9    9    a            NA  NA
# 10  10    n            NA  NA
# 11  11    d             2   2
# 12  12    f             2   2
# 13  13    d             2   2
# 14  14    a             2   2
# 15  15    t            NA  NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Again, in base-R, bit nasty, but has a smaller number of iterations and no if elses.

```
library(data.table)
in.data <- data.table(colA=c("b", "f", "b", "k", "d", "b", "a", "s", "a", "n", "d", "f", "d", "a", "t"))
in.data$out <- rep(NA,nrow(in.data))

d <- which(in.data$colA=="d")
a <- which(in.data$colA=="a")
end <- rep(NA, length(d))
for (i in seq_along(d)){
  begin <-  d[i]
if(begin>=max(a)) # this cdn accomodates a case where no "a" appears after some "d"
      break
  end[i] <- min(a[d[i]<a])
  in.data$out[begin: end[i]] <-  sum(!is.na(unique(end)))
}
in.data
#    colA out
# 1:    b  NA
# 2:    f  NA
# 3:    b  NA
# 4:    k  NA
# 5:    d   1
# 6:    b   1
# 7:    a   1
# 8:    s  NA
# 9:    a  NA
#10:    n  NA
#11:    d   2
#12:    f   2
#13:    d   2
#14:    a   2
#15:    t  NA
```

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be comically complicated, but it has no loops or matching (and so should be fast):

```
library(zoo)

in.data[, newcol := (colA=='d') - (colA=='a')
      ][newcol == 0 & 1:.N > 1, newcol := NA
      ][, newcol := na.locf(newcol, F)
      ][newcol < 0, newcol := 0
      ][, newcol := newcol * cumsum(diff(c(0, newcol)) != 0)
      ][newcol == 0 & c(NA, head(newcol, -1)), newcol := NA
      ][, newcol := na.locf(newcol, F)
      ][newcol != 0, newcol := .GRP, by = newcol][]
#    colA wanted.column newcol
# 1:    b            NA      0
# 2:    f            NA      0
# 3:    b            NA      0
# 4:    k            NA      0
# 5:    d             1      1
# 6:    b             1      1
# 7:    a             1      1
# 8:    s            NA      0
# 9:    a            NA      0
#10:    n            NA      0
#11:    d             2      2
#12:    f             2      2
#13:    d             2      2
#14:    a             2      2
#15:    t            NA      0
```

Each step is very simple and should be self-explanatory if you run it step by step.

Comment: It will not produce the right answer on these examples: `in.data <- data.table(colA=c("d", "b", "a", "d", "f", "d", "t"))` and `in.data <- data.table(colA=c("b", "f", "b", "k", "d", "b", "a", "d", "f", "d", "a", "t"))`

Comment: @MaratTalipov Thanks! I knew those a's followed by d's were trouble. It's fixed now, but involves a ridiculous number of steps.

Answer (score 3):

A bit nasty to be honest but it worked for me:

```
library(data.table)
in.data <- data.table(colA=c("b", "f", "b", "k", "d", "b", "a", "s", "a", "n", "d", "f", "d", "a", "t"))

in.data$out <- rep(NA,nrow(in.data))

activator <- FALSE
counter <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(in.data)) {
      if (activator == TRUE & in.data$colA[i] !='a') {
        in.data$out[i] <- counter
        next
      }
      if( in.data$colA[i]=='d') {
        activator <- TRUE
        in.data$out[i] <- counter
      } else if (in.data$colA[i]=='a' & activator==TRUE ) {
        in.data$out[i] <- counter
        counter <- counter + 1
        activator <- FALSE
      } else {next}
}
in.data
```

Output:

```
> in.data
    colA out
 1:    b  NA
 2:    f  NA
 3:    b  NA
 4:    k  NA
 5:    d   1
 6:    b   1
 7:    a   1
 8:    s  NA
 9:    a  NA
10:    n  NA
11:    d   2
12:    f   2
13:    d   2
14:    a   2
15:    t  NA
```

You could do a `sapply` if you want instead but the `if` statements are so many that a `for-loop` might be clearer to read...

Comment: That's solves the problem but I don't see any data table syntax here unfortunately

Comment: That's because I didn't use any. The OP doesn't mention he needs a solution with `data.table` syntax. He just said he uses a `data.table`

Comment: I guess adding [tag:data.table] implies it... Though may this will work for him too, don't know

Comment: I just ran this in my real data, and it takes close to a minute, so a faster way is very appreciated.

Comment: It works though doesn't it? I guess posting it as a different question would attract people to answer it. It took me 30mins to come up with a solution, it would take me a lot of time to try something else....

Comment: Probably rewriting the above in parallel would be the best solution . Also close to a minute doesn't seem like a lot of time to me .... In fact even running in parallel might not work since the overhead required will probably increase the time to over a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested rigorously, but here's another one to the bunch:

```
require(data.table)
cj_dt = CJ(which(in.data$colA == "d"), which(in.data$colA == "a"))[V1 <= V2]
idx1 = cj_dt[, if (.N > 1) list(V2 = V2[1L]), by=V1]
idx2 = cj_dt[!idx1][, list(V1 = V1[1L]), by=V2]
ans = rbind(idx1, idx2)

#    V1 V2
# 1:  5  7
# 2: 11 14
```

Now all we've to do is to replace `5:7, 11:14` of `wanted.column` with `1`.

Does anyone see a scenario where this would break?